# How to remove some texts from a field during a select query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field in my table that contains this value:

```
#3 text For string# 1
#4 Payment For Inv# 5
```

What I want to do here is to only display "1 and 5" after a select query, and the problem is that #n is not limited to a single digit only thus, I cannot use SUBSTRING.

Any ideas on how to proceed with this?

Comment: can you please specify what exactly the field contains and what exactly is the desirable output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 1 and 5 comes at last position of string so you get the last character of string as

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(YOUR_COLUMN, ' ', -1) FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

If its 1 digit number, always on the right of the string, use [`RIGHT()`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-right-function.php) :

```
SELECT RIGHT(t.YourColumn) FROM YourTable t
```